# Returned enum type not recognised

Tags: python, enums

I am trying to use python's Enum type for a `state` variable.

Problem is: when I call `bar()` from `file2.py` its return type (supposedly `State`) is not recognised in the main loop.

`main.py`:

```
from enum import Enum
from file2 import bar


class State(Enum):
    STATE_1 = 1
    STATE_2 = 2
    STATE_3 = 3


def foo():
    return State.STATE_2


def main():
    state = State.STATE_1
    while True:
        print(state)
        print(type(state) is State)

        match state:
            case State.STATE_1:
                print("in state 1")
                state = foo()
            case State.STATE_2:
                print("in state 2")
                state = bar()
            case State.STATE_3:
                print("in state 3")
                state = State.STATE_1
            case _:
                print("incorrect state")
                break
        input()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`file2.py`:

```
def bar():
    from main import State

    return State.STATE_3
```

output is:

```
State.STATE_1
True
in state 1

State.STATE_2
True
in state 2

State.STATE_3
False
incorrect state
```

Comment: How exactly are you executing this? I suspect the problem is that you have *two* separate modules created from `main.py` (and thus creating two distinct `State` classes): `__main__` created by executing `main.py` as a script, and `main` created by importing `main.py` from `bar.py`.

Comment: And `__main__.State.STATE_3` is *not* the same as `main.State.STATE_3`.

Comment: I changed `from main import State` to `from __main__ import State` and it worked thanks! Would checking for equality rather than identity change anything ?

Comment: Possibly; I don't recall how enum equality is handled. You should probably try to avoid the import cycle without importing directly from `__main__`, though. Move `State` to its own module and have both `main.py` and `bar.py` import that instead.

Comment: @chepner: No, using `==` would not work, since  both `Enum` and `Flag` use identity for equality checks.